# grep-like filter in office suites (OpenOffice)

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

The GNU `grep` command allows to search inside the incoming stream of data, for example inside the files. It have two similar and very useful CLI parameters: `-A` & `-B`:

```
-Annn shows nnn lines following the line where the match was found ("after")
-Bnnn - same, but show the lines preceding the matching one ("before")
```

It is very convenient in analyzing long lists with rare matches in order to see the match's environment. Right now I need to reproduce such behavior in the spreadsheet, but have no idea how to...

I have a table of asset tags like (non-essential columns removed):

```
CNT306621   OK
CNT306631   OK
CNT306632   OK
CNT306751   Bad!
CNT306761   OK
CNT306771   OK
```

The sequential asset tags (CNT30xxxZ) must differ in the `xxx` part, and the next AT's `xxx` must be same as previous, or 1+previous one. `Z` part is out of scope and `CNT30` is a constant.

That's why 663 is OK after 662, and second 663 is also OK after first one. But 675 must be after 674, not after 663. Number of mismatches is about 30 for the table with about 1000 lines.

Some mismatches are "rightful" - every department have its own range of tags, for example R&D have from CNT30`660`1 to CNT30`674`9, but for now uses only 660..663, with 664..674 are reserved for future use. Then Accounting have from CNT30`675`1 to CNT30`690`9, thus making normal the "Bad!" mark because the last tag **used** by R&D is not the last one from R&D's **assigned** range.

But some times some tags could be assigned in inconsistent way:

```
CNT306751   OK
CNT306761   OK
CNT306771   OK
CNT306791   Bad!
CNT306801   OK
CNT306812   OK
```

Where is Accounting's tag of CNT3067`8`1? And such mismatch is not normal and a subject of my "investigation" - either a tag was unintentionally missed during assignment, either it was carelessly removed. To save my eyes, I need to reduce the table to the "Bad!" lines and their closes ones to check if the mismatch "rightful" or not.
Should it be plain text file, I could use `grep` on it, creating reduced output with 1-2 lines before and after "Bad!" one for fast clarification. But it is the spreadsheet document and I hope to utilize its filtering capabilities.

Is that possible?

PS. I can export a spreadsheet into plaintext, then grep it for anything I need, but it is for the last resort.
Also I can write a macro which will scan the sheet and copy the appropriate lines to another sheet. But what about the built-in filtering engine?

Comment: Why don't you just filter on the relevant column? Please explain what the desired result is. Show us a before and after data set

Comment: Because filter shows only exact values.

for example, I have (in column): 1,2,4,3,5,4,5,6,7,4,8

and I need to select only rows with "4" AND adjacent rows - one before row with "4" and one after such row. And if "row before" contains 3, or 4, then it is OK, otherwise it is not OK. Any idea with filters? And without formulae?